# SQL ARITHMETIC OPERATION

Tags: sql

I am trying to get the sum of two rows using (+) operator in select. But when one column is null, the column for the SUM will also be null.

```
Select SALES_ID, FY19.SALES_2019, FY20.SALES_2020, (SALES_2019 + SALES_2020) as TOTAL_SALES
FROM
(Select Sales_id, sum(sales_amount) from sales_table where sales_year = '2019')FY19
LEFT JOIN
(Select Sales_id, sum(sales_amount) from sales_table where sales_year = '2020')FY20
ON FY19.sales_id = FY20.sales_id
```

If 2019 have sales amount of 20,000 and 2020 with 0 or null, the TOTAL_SALES will also be NULL
I am wondering if there is a way to make the TOTAL_SALES be 20,000 too.

Comment: Have you tried using IFNULL(SALES_2019, 0) + IFNULL(SALES_2020,0) ?

Comment: I have tried using the COALESCE function, and it worked now. Thanks!

Comment: Do you store year values as character data type?!?

Comment: The @Popeye code is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the conditional aggregation as follows:

```
Select SALES_ID, 
       sum(case when sales_year = '2019' then sales_amount end) as SALES_2019, 
       sum(case when sales_year = '2020' then sales_amount end) as SALES_2020, 
       sum(sales_amount) as TOTAL_SALES
 FROM sales_table where sales_year in ('2019','2020')
```

Comment: Unless OP intends to group by `SALES_ID`, there is no reason to have `SALES_ID` in this query (as the result will be indeterminate). To make the query make sense, there probably should be a `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is wrong and incomprehensible.

```
(Select Sales_id, sum(sales_amount) from sales_table where sales_year = '2019')FY19
LEFT JOIN
(Select Sales_id, sum(sales_amount) from sales_table where sales_year = '2020')FY20
ON FY19.sales_id = FY20.sales_id
```

The above code snippet does not work because it never equals

This code gives the total sales each year:

```
select sales_year,SUM(sales_amount) as TOTAL_SALES
from sales_table
group by sales_year
```